Why is my data not being stored in localStorage using Plasmo Storage?
I'm using the Plasmo Storage library to manage data storage in my web application. I have two functions, getBooks and setBook, to retrieve and store a list of books in localStorage. However, the data does not seem to be saving to localStorage as expected. Here is my code:
import { Storage } from "@plasmohq/storage";

export type Book = {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  genre: string;
  url: string;
  lastRead: string;
};

const storage = new Storage({ area: "local" });

export const getBooks = async (): Promise<Book[]> => {
  try {
    const books = await storage.get<Book[]>("books");
    console.log("getBooks - books retrieved:", books);
    return books ?? [];
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error retrieving books:", error);
    return [];
  }
};

export const setBook = async (book: Book): Promise<void> => {
  const bookList = await getBooks();
  bookList.push(book);
  try {
    await storage.set("books", bookList);
    console.log("Book added successfully:", book);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error setting book:", error);
  }
};

I've checked the console logs, and while the functions are being called, the data isn't being stored in localStorage. What could be causing this issue? Am I missing something in my implementation or configuration?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
